# Field requires API level 21 (current min is 14): android.content.Context#TELECOM_SERVICE

Tags: android

I am using

```
TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
String deviceId=tm.getDeviceId();
```

to get device IMEI. 
But is shows warning

> field requires API level 21 (current min is 14):
>   android.content.Context#TELECOM_SERVICE

What does it mean? And how to solve this?

I am using

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

And also this is not working:

`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), deviceId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: *What does it mean?* Android's basics: there is many versions of android (please, read at least original android's guides)... *And how to solve this?* obviously: do not use it or do not support lower API versions

Comment: `TELECOM_SERVICE`..? Did you mean `TELEPHONY_SERVICE`? And _"this is not working"_ is a really poor problem description. You need to be more detailed than that.

Comment: "this is not working" means the toast is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Use `TELEPHONY_SERVICE` instead of `TELECOM_SERVICE` like below:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// get IMEI
String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
```